# How to find the probability distribution for the following random variable?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have an exponential random variable $X$ with parameter $\lambda$. I want to find the distribution of $Y$ where $$Y=aX+\frac{1}{X}$$ where $a>0$ is a constant. Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Let $t>0$. Write $\{Y<t\}$ as $(X- u)^{2}<v$ where $u= \frac t {2a}$,v=\frac {x^{2}} {4a^{2}}+ \frac 1 a$ Take it up from here.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment. Its really helpful